# Screen Readability: Overlay transparant layer

Tags: screen, transparency, image-viewers, kindle

I was wondering whether it'd be possible to overlay transparent images over folders, the desktop, browser, etc.

Sort of like an image viewer, just transparent.

This question arose since I'm trying to figure out how to create a higher readability and comfort for reading. I spend a lot of time on different monitors, all with different adjustments, resolutions, etc. Solutions I found (but aren't ideal) are sct (temperature) and xrandr (brightness). Both options are good to have at hand (and highly modifiable, which is great).

The problem I have with (most) screens is that they are mirror-like instead of kindle-like, that is, they seem to be lacking a rough structure or texture. That's why I'm looking for an overlay with rough structures. Most programs only seem to offer color and brightness options, but never structure/texture.

In that regard, what could help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be useful for tracing.
All the drawing softwares have layer capabilities but some webapps don't.
Think of Inkarnate, the online map drawing tool: if you have the free version you can just draw and not upload a base image.
With a transparent superimposed image you could follow and trace shapes without uploading anything.